# Delete objects in Array in sequence but first one

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to remove objects in the array from the end in sequence So I tried to use `pop` and `splice`
but for some reason, when I use the `pop` function then  all the objects are removed, and got an error :
`is not a function`  and when I use the `splice` function then all the objects are removed
here is my code :

```js
const [appendChartData, setAppendChartData] = useState(chartData.datasets);
const appendAxis = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    setAppendChartData([...appendChartData, AppendData]);
  };
    const deleteAxis = () => {
      setAppendChartData(appendChartData.splice(-1, 1));
     /// setAppendChartData(appendChartData.pop());
  };
```

## chartData.datasets

```js
export let chartData =[  {
    labels: defaultLabels,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "dataSetting",
        data: defaultDatas,
        backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor,
      },]
```

## AppendData

```js
export let AppendData = {
  label: "dataSetting",
  data: defaultDatas,
  backgroundColor: defaultBackgroundColor,
};
```

so I'd like to remove the array in sequence from the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you used the state is wrong. You should use the chartData as state:

```
const [appendChartData, setAppendChartData] = useState(chartData);

const appendAxis = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    setAppendChartData({
        ...appendChartData,
        datasets: [
           ...appendChartData.datasets,
           AppendData
        ]
    });
};

const deleteAxis = () => {
    setAppendChartData({
        ...appendChartData,
        datasets: appendChartData.datasets.splice(-1, 1)
    });
};
```

Also, be careful about your `chartData` since I saw that you defined it as an array of objects. If that's true then you must consider it in the code above.

Comment: OH ! that's why !!! Thank you so much !!! it really help me !!!